# Creating a User Schema but am getting ReferenceError: Cannot access 'UserSchema" before initialization

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

everything works fin until I add the friends to the user schema.
how do I get this to work? Im trying to allow users to have friends.  Is there something small I am missing while trying to nest this document?

```
     const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
    },
    pictures: {
        type: String,
    },
    nickName: {
        type: String
    },
    relationshipStatus: {
        type: String,
    },
    nextTrip: {
        type: String,
    },
    reasonTravel: {
        type: String,
    },
    language: {
        type: String,
    },
    lastLocation: {
        type: String,
    },
    loveLanguage: {
        type: String,
    },
    travelGoals: {
        type: String,
    },
    education: {
        type: String,
    },
    friends: {
        type: [UserSchema]
    }
   
 
}, { timestamps: true });



UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    const user = this;
    if(!user.isModified('password')){
        return next();
    }
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt)=>{
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash)=>{
            if(err){
                return next(err)
            }
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        })
    })
})
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword){
    const user = this;
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }
            if(!isMatch){
                return reject(false);
            }
            resolve(true);
        })
    })
}


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

/Users/noahduran/Langiddy_msg/server/models/User.js:51
type: [UserSchema]
^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'UserSchema' before initialization
at Object. (/Users/noahduran/Langiddy_msg/server/models/User.js:51:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (/Users/noahduran/Langiddy_msg/server/config/jwt.config.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to self-reference the schema in one of its properties, try to use `this`:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ...
    friends: {
      type: [this],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: this seems to have worked!